# If isset ID inside array, get values from defined ID in same array?

Tags: php

If user access my page using an ID: `mysite.com/page.php?id=3`, I want the PHP to check if ID is defined in an array, if true, it returns in page multiple user information from same array according to their defined IDs.

My code:

```
$userinfo = [
        ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'username3', 'phone' => '3333'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'username2', 'phone' => '2222'],
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'username1', 'phone' => '1111']
    ];  

if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($userinfo[$_GET['id']])) {
     $name = $userinfo[$_GET['name']]; // If I access PHP with '?id=3' wanna 'username3'.
     $phone = $userinfo[$_GET['phone']]; // It stores id 3 user phone: '3333'
    }

echo $name; // It returns 'name' from array.
echo $phone; // It returns 'phone' from array.
```

It's only a base, I know it don't works, any help with the code? thanks in advance.

Comment: you need a loop for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the array for what you need:

```
$userinfo = [
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'username3', 'phone' => '3333'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'username2', 'phone' => '2222'],
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'username1', 'phone' => '1111']
];  

$user = null;
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $found = array_filter($userinfo, function ($user) {
           return isset($user["id"]) && $user["id"] == $_GET["id"];
    }); // This will find all users with that id, in case there's more.
    $user = !empty($found)?current($found):null; //current() at this point gets the first entry in $found
}
if ($user != null) {
   echo $user["name"];
   echo $user["phone"];
}
```

Check out [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for you help, friend!

Comment: Alive to Die code is good, but I was having some problems with it according to my code, this is awesome, no problems here! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$userinfo = [
        ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'username3', 'phone' => '3333'],
        ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'username2', 'phone' => '2222'],
        ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'username1', 'phone' => '1111']
    ];  
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    foreach($userinfo as $user){
        if($user['id']==$_GET['id']){
            $name = $user['name'];  
            $phone = $user['phone'];
        }
    }
}
echo $name;  
echo $phone;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for any depth of the associated array. Just constraint to this function is that the key value would not be repeat any where in array.

```
<?php 
function assoc_in_array($array, $key, $key_value){
      $within_array = false;
      foreach( $array as $k=>$v ){
          if( is_array($v) ){
              $within_array = assoc_in_array($v, $key, $key_value);
              if( $within_array == true ){
                    break;
              }
          } else {
                if( $v == $key_value && $k == $key ){
                    $within_array = true;
                    break;
                }
          }
      }
      return $within_array;
}
$test = [
            ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'username3', 'phone' => '3333'],
            ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'username2', 'phone' => '2222'],
        ];
var_dump(assoc_in_array($test, 'id', '3'));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!